# High Average Access Time on SSD

Tags: 20.04, ssd, performance

I have a problem:
I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on SSD: [Western Digital Green, 480Gb (WDS480G2G0B)](https://shop.westerndigital.com/en-ie/products/internal-drives/wd-green-sata-ssd#WDS480G2G0B)
Benchmarks showed me very high access time: about `2` ms! (also, I did `sudo fstrim -va` before running the benchmark)
[image: SSD benchmark]

On another laptop (with different SSD), this number is about `0.02` ms

I followed [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive_#Resolving_NCQ_errors) and disabled NCQ: `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/queue_depth`
this helped me to achieve `0.3` ms (about 10 times better), but it is still very high for an SSD.

I am thinking that this is a software problem rather than hardware.

So, what do you think, maybe somebody had such issue as well?
How can I decrease this high latency?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
Found [similar problem](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/brand-new-120gb-wd-green-ssd-slow-asf.249296/) on WD Green SSD
It seems that this is definitely hardware problem

**UPDATE 2**
According to the [phoronix benchmarks](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=samsung-860-qvo&num=3), `WD Green` is the slowest and the worst SSD

Comment: Please do not post answers in the question. Create an answer so we can upvote it and you can accept it. It is allowed to self-answer questions!

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is indeed in SSD, but not in Ubuntu or laptop.

So, I returned back WD Green and purchased SAMSUNG SSD 860 EVO
The results are impressive (for me at least) 0.06 msec instead of 1.75:
[image]

**Conclusion**: The reason of high latency was in WD Green SSD.

If you want a low latency SSD - don't buy WD Green.
SAMSUNG, in my experience, is the most low latency and reliable SSD (I use it on 3 laptops, and 4 PCs)